# How to create trigger that transfer data from one table to another tabke

Tags: oracle

How to create `Trigger` that transfer the sum of multiple rows to another table,  i have two `column` qty and prise i want to transfer the sum of multiple `rows` to another `table` ex supplier

Comment: what have you already tried?

Comment: Why **trigger**? Why not stored procedure, or - when we're at it - an ordinary `insert`?

Comment: Ok maybe i didnt explain clearly i have table purchasing contains two coulmn qty and price i have supplier who supply to me many products i want to transfer the sum of total for this supplier to table of supplier

Answer (score 0):

Not tested but you need to try something like this..your question is missing test data and also table information so i did understand what do you mean by adding sum of multiple rows...but this might give you an idea:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER TG_NAME
    AFTER INSERT ON supplier
    FOR EACH ROW
    DECLARE
        CURSOR cur_name IS
            SELECT SUM (qty + price) sum_rows
              FROM purchasing;

        vRowStudent cur_name%ROWTYPE;
    BEGIN
        OPEN cur_name;
        FETCH cur_name INTO vRowStudent;
        CLOSE cur_name;
        INSERT INTO supplier
        (sup_column)
        VALUES (vRowStudent.sum_rows);
    END TG_NAME;
```

Comment: Ok maybe i didnt explain clearly i have table purchasing contains two coulmn qty and price i have supplier who supply to me many products i want to transfer the sum of total for this supplier to table of supplier

Comment: have you tried my example ..did you expect something like this ? or better provide some test data and expected output result

Comment: I have try it and i get nothing

Comment: Can you give me your number to contact with you on whatsapp

Comment: Andrew can you give me your number